# Unit testing and mocking mySQL database in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, unit-testing, sqlite, sequelize.js

In my Node.js API I'm connecting to a mySQL database using [promise-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql). I'm using [Sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize) as ORM. I want to unit test each micro service interacting with the database.

Obviously during the tests, I don't want to create a real database connection since unit tests should not rely on dependencies like database connections. Rather I want to mock it, using either an in-memory or on-disc database like [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3).

I've tried migrating the SQL dump to [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) but I get errors since the dump is not compatible with [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3). The data set is modest in size.

Can you recommend an approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be use `mysql in memory table`. That will very fast like `sqlite3`.

And other ways is that create migration file (I worked with knex.js) and rather than dumping, create seed file.

Comment: What Node.js module would you use for mysql in-memory tabled? Doesn't look like promise-mysql supports this.

Comment: check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html

Comment: I ended up dumping my SQL database into CSV files and then loading the CSV files into sqlite3 using an on-disc database. It works well with smaller data sets.

Here the gist:
https://gist.github.com/ChristianRich/a7e086c76ecd0db1c78ae5e15b11606d